# control focus issue in windows application having dev express grid

Tags: visual-studio-2013, devexpress, winapp

I am working on window application having dev. express grid whose tab index is set 35,  and a text box having tab index 1, but when page loads tab stops on grid's find panel. I want focus  on the text  box. I tried to set focus on load event but not working.

Answer (score 0):

### **got the answer..........**

```
private void frmCustomer_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtCustomerName.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                txtCustomerName.Select();
            }));
        }
```